# how to restrict category creation more than certain number in magento

Tags: category

My need is :

If I set category limit is 50.
when I try to create a 51-th category that will not be created
How I do this in magento.

and also,

how to I set limit for products like above.

any easy way available for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using observer, I am adding xml code here :
Step 1:create config file:

> app/code/local/Sipping/Disable/etc/config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Sipping_Disable>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sipping_Disable>
      </modules>
    <adminhtml>
            <events>
                <catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <sipping_disable>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>disable/observer</class>
                        <method>catalog_product_save_before</method>
                    </sipping_disable>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_before>

            <catalog_category_save_before>
                        <observers>
                            <sipping_disable>
                                <type>singleton</type>
                                <class>disable/observer</class>
                                <method>catalog_category_save_before</method>
                            </sipping_disable>
                        </observers>
            </catalog_category_save_before>
         </events>

        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

Step 2:Create observer file:

> app/code/local/Sipping/Disable/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Sipping_Disable_Model_Observer
{

    public function catalog_product_save_before($observer)
    {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSize();
            if(intval($collection) > 50){
                // Do something here.
            }


    }

    public function catalog_category_save_before($observer)
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->getSize();

        if(intval($collection) > 50){
            // Do something here.
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: But  Where i add the dispatch event method [ "Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_category_save_before',array($sss=>sss));  ] to respond this. could you  tell me the full code for this.